# Vulkan SDK Redistributables

Tags: c++, c, vulkan

I post the following question at LunarG, as Issue #565, about Vulkan SDK redistributable parts for ready to go applications developed with Vulkan. I'd like to share it with Stack Overflow developers.

> Let's say I have Vulkan application demo and wish to send it to
>   potential clients, in order to evaluate it. If I'd develop it using
>   SDK, what is the correct way to deploy it :
>
> a) include the compatible SDK installer in a multi-install process ?
>
> b) include some SDK's dlls and companion files ? Which ones ?
>
> It also raises another question: Can I re-distribute SDK files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karl Schultz, from LunarG, replied with the following:

> On Windows, many IHVs include the Vulkan loader DLL in their install
>   packages, placing it in system32/vulkan-1.dll. So, in many cases, your
>   app might just work fine as long as the user has installed drivers
>   with Vulkan support.
>
> You might also consider shipping only the RunTimeInstaller, which is
>   found in the SDK. This would let the user install the run time
>   (loader) as part of your application install. The RTI includes version
>   checking so that it doesn't clobber a newer version installed by IHV
>   drivers, or vice-versa. In short, this is probably the best way to go.
>   It would be better to include the RTI as part of the "multi-install
>   process" rather than include the entire SDK.
>
> If your application needs layers or some other specific item from the
>   SDK, then you'd have to include those explicitly somehow.
>
> Please check the licensing-related files within the SDK concerning
>   redistribution.

Comment: The VulkanRT installer seems to be sort of "reference counted" so I would add, that it should be part of your App uninstaller too.

Comment: @krOoze I guess its easy to flag installer to include Vulkan RTI on removal process when uninstalling. I used to work with InstallShield, and it is quite easy to set this feature,  but I'll give a chance for newer and less expensive tools ;)